# How to correctly create a simple Spring project running in the console using the last STS version (3.8.4.RELEASE)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

today I downloaded the last **STS** version (**3.8.4.RELEASE**) and I have some doubts because it seems to me that something is changed.

I have to create a simple batch application (running in the console).

It seems to me that to create this kind of project in this new realease I have to do:

> **File --> Spring Legacy Project --> Simple Spring Maven**

It seems to me that there is no other way to create a simple console project. Why this kind of project are putted under the **Spring Legacy Project**? Can I do the same thing in a more modern way?

Another doubt is related to the **Spring Version** into the **pom.xml** file:

```
<spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
```

Why the default version is the **3.2.3.RELEASE**? Can I replace it with the more m odern Spring 4^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As its name says "Spring Legacy Project" is a legacy functionality. It create old Spring projects.

Spring now is promoting Spring Boot applications, these applications have everything you need configured by default. You only need to add the dependencies that you need.

Now you need to use:

File -- > New -- Spring Starter Project

On the first view you configure the project. Where is located, maven or gradle, etc.

On the second view you choose the libraries that you will use in your porject. You choose if it is a web project, or if you need jdbc or jpa, or batch processing.

In your case, if you don't need a web application, you just don't added to the project.

You can see more about Spring boot here

https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Comment: I know Spring Boot but from what I know it always contains a Tomcat server embedded, or am I missing something? Can I create a console batch application using Spring Boot without including Tomcat in it?

Comment: If you need to use tomcat, you need to add "Web" and "tomcat" dependencies. If you need a console application you don't need to add those dependencies. You need to add batch dependency and that's all. It's a fully runable console application.

Comment: And doing in this way what changes respect to my legacy Spring application?

Comment: Spring boot includes the dependencies you need to work, if you need a database application, it will include all the dependencies to connect to make a jdbc application and those dependencies are tested to work together. In the legacy Spring application you need to look for dependencies and see what version of those dependencies work with the dependencies of your project. Now Spring boot does all those things for you.